# php: getting database name from own mysli class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, wrapper

i made a wrapper class for mysqli with the following syntax:

```
class mydb extends mysqli
{
     ....
}
```

i'm creating instances like the following:

```
$conn = new mydb($host $username , $pass, $dbname);
```

i'm wondering - how can i access `$dbname` from inside the class?
i'm looking for an mysqli equivalent for the `mysql_db_name()` function.

Comment: That looks like an unecessary wrapper to me

Comment: If your unsure on how to approach a Wrapper, then study one that's already in use. https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always make your own class that has a field variable with a reference to a mysqli object and database name.

```
class MyDatabase {

    public $dbi;
    public $dbname;

    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        $this->dbi = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        $this->dbname = $db;
    }

}

$mydb = new MyDatabase($host, $user, $pass, $db);

//Access db name that was stored during connection
echo $mydb->dbname;
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use this SQL query from your own class:

```
SELECT database() AS the_db
```

That should show you the current DB you have selected.

Comment: this should be the best answer in my opinion

Comment: This is the best answer.